# Преобразовать два списка в один

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, for

Есть два списка с именами, телефонами и ключами 
`(BMW, AUDI, Berlin, Praga)`, 
`:` разделитель.

Нужно проверить, являются ли ключи в каждом элементе списка `name` полностью равны ключам любого из элементов `phone`. Если есть совпадения, то вывести список с первым значением каждого элемента `name` и `phone` согласно ключам, то есть имя и телефон.

```
name = ['Alex:Praga:BMW', 'Kolya:Berlin:Audi', 'Greg:Paris:Ford', 'John:Paris:Ford']
phone = ['74957758888:Berlin:Audi', '74999224831:Paris:Ford', '74952122159:Praga:BMW']

result = ['Alex:74952122159', 'Kolya:74957758888', 'Greg:74999224831', 'John:74999224831']
```

Comment: а каков шанс того что не случится, например следующее: `name = ['Nikita:Berlin:Audi','Alex:Berlin:Audi','Greg:Paris:Ford']` `phone = ['74957758888:Berlin:Audi','74999224831:Paris:Ford','74957759999:Berlin:Audi']`

Comment: Получается в таком случае `Nikita` получает `74957758888`, а `Alex` - `74957759999`?

Comment: Исключения не важны, я их сам как-нибудь проработаю. Мне главное основу кода. Понимаю, что можно использовать for и .split , но не получается скомпоновать вместе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не особо уверен в правильности вашей архитектуры, но допускаю, что двум людям может принадлежать один номер. Тогда можно реализовать следующий алгоритм. Соберем каждое значение и разобьем по `:`, а затем сверим ключи имён и ключи телефонов (`name_key` и `phone_key` соответственно)

```
def get_matching_phones(name_list, phone_list):
    output_list = []
    for name_entry in name_list:
        name_parts = name_entry.split(':')
        name_key = name_parts[1] + ':' + name_parts[2]

        for phone_entry in phone_list:
            phone_parts = phone_entry.split(':')
            phone_key = phone_parts[1] + ':' + phone_parts[2]

            if name_key == phone_key:
                output_list.append(f"{name_parts[0]}:{phone_parts[0]}")
                break

    return output_list
```

Я немного изменил входные данные, чтобы обогатить тест.

```
name = ['Alex:Praga:BMW', 'Kolya:Berlin:Audi', 'Greg:Paris:Ford', 'John:Paris:Ford', 'Acinit:Samara:Lada', 'Acinit:Berlin:Audi']
phone = ['74957758888:Berlin:Audi', '74999224831:Paris:Ford','79053455232:Samara:Lada', '74952122159:Praga:BMW','74999212345:Berlin:Audi']

result = get_matching_phones(name, phone)
print(result)
```

Вывод в терминале:

```
['Alex:74952122159', 'Kolya:74957758888', 'Greg:74999224831', 'John:74999224831', 'Acinit:79053455232', 'Acinit:74957758888']
```

p.s. здесь мы можем видеть проблему того, что у `Acinit` ожидаются по ключу `Berlin:Audi` номер `74999212345`, но вместо этого он берет самый первый в списке подходящий аргумент, а именно номер `Kolya` - `74957758888`.

Если данное считается ошибкой, сообщите об этом в комментариях

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
name = ['Alex:Praga:BMW', 'Kolya:Berlin:Audi', 'Greg:Paris:Ford', 'John:Paris:Ford']
phone = ['74957758888:Berlin:Audi', '74999224831:Paris:Ford', '74952122159:Praga:BMW']

name = {v[:v.find(':')]: v[v.find(':'):] for v in name}
phone = {v[v.find(':'):]: v[:v.find(':')] for v in phone}

list_rez = []
for k, v in name.items():
    r = phone.get(v)
    if r:
        list_rez.append(f'{k}:{r}')

print(*list_rez)
```